# Taylor expansion of a function in powers of $x-\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

Consider the Taylor expansion of the function $\frac{1}{1+x^3}$ in powers of $x-\frac{1}{2}$: $$\frac{1}{1+x^3}=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n(x-\frac{1}{2})^n.$$ What is the radius of convergence of this series?

I wanted to write $$\frac{1}{1+x^3}=\frac{1}{1+(\frac{1}{2}+x-\frac{1}{2})^3}$$ and the expand it. But then I am facing difficulty in handling the coefficients. Please help how to solve this problem.

Comment: what is the difficulty you encountered? It may be helpful to write $y=x-1/2$ and expand around $y=0$

Comment: I think then you need to solve a recursion if you need explicit coefficients

Comment: Hint: how the radius of convergence is related to the singularities?

Comment: It must not include singularities.

Answer (score 2):

Following the comment of @user58697, we do it through complex analysis.

We know that the radius of convergence of the power series of an analytic function is the distance to the nearest singularity. The singularities of $1+x^3$ are $$x=-1, -w, -w^2,$$ where $w$ is the cube root of unity.

Of these singuarities, the  nearest one to $\frac{1}{2}$ is $$-\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}$$ and its distance from $\frac{1}{2}$ is $$\bigg|\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}\bigg|=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$